# Questions about how to establish or fix a relationship are too broad

Tags: discussion, scope

[How to be accepted back into a group](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/221/110)

For this site to work I really think that we have to limit ourselves to well focused questions. Questions need to focus on specific situations and the skills to use in them. There's no single interpersonal skill which you can point to for solving the problem of a mean or unaccepting friendship group - it will take dozens of interactions and dozens of skills. Answers will make lots of assumptions and veer off in widely different directions.

I suspect these questions may be so common that they would warrant a custom close reason.

Comment: With regard to that particular question, I don't think it's wise we advise them to get back with these "friends" as the way he is being treated is rather bad given they are "friends". However with other examples I can see why they want advice (however I feel an "apology" would be better than just trying to "fix" it.)

Answer (score -1):

## I don't think so.

Relationships are *complicated.* I think that limiting ourselves to problems that require minimal use of the very skills that this site was created to help with makes the scope much too narrow.

Comment: What do you mean by "minimal use"? How is that related to what I wrote?