# Closure: 'How to intensify tone politely to someone who may be ignoring your reminder emails?'

Tags: support, reopen-request

[How to chase tactfully someone who ignores your multiple reminder emails?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/2833/2423) was closed as 'too broad', but [this user](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/2833/how-to-intensify-tone-politely-to-someone-who-may-be-ignoring-your-reminder-emai#comment11669_2833) and I don't judge it as broad?

I've since edited and added more details to it.

Comment: But five other users judged the question to be off topic, so you need to explain why it's not, and that means you have to spend longer than two minutes writing your meta request. And lastly, although you have found an ally, it does not necessarily mean everyone agrees.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I can't explain if I don't know why they judged so ?

Comment: You explain why your question is NOT too broad, and why it is on topic for this site.

Comment: If you happened to downvote my [meta question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/is-too-broad-being-confused-with-too-verbose-or-too-vague), which specifically inquires why some questions are classed as  "too broad" then you haven't understood a thing. If you didn't downvote, then maybe you might be interested in reading and understanding what "too broad" means on IPS.

Comment: Canada - that other user is not a good exemplar here. On most of the sites I moderate, that comment would be seen as a little rant, flagged and deleted.

Comment: @RoryAlsop thank you for pointing who the ally is, the same user who posted this question on meta https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1707/dealing-with-bigotry-on-this-forum-while-asking-how-to-deal-with-arrogance

Comment: One user who is disgruntled with the system is not good proof that the community should agree.  Considering there seem to be several of these questions that are closed for similar reasons, I think the problem may lie in your insistence that they belong here.

Answer (score 0):

Editing a closed/on hold question automatically puts it back on the reopen queue. You only edited the question 15 minutes ago. Give it some time for people to see your edits. Not every single post has to be discussed individually on meta.

As you can see:

[image]

Just have some patience.

Comment: Actually, this only works if the question is edited within the first five days of it being "on hold". Otherwise, it doesn't go into the review queue but the OP can flag it or (if they have sufficient reputation) nominate it for reopening themselves: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/284336 This question was closed for ~20 days before being edited.

Comment: ... well, it's more complicated than that... it was edited within the five-day window but the edits didn't substantially change the post, so it was unlikely anyone actually ... yeah, I think I'll just write an answer... give me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

So, *yes* what Jarko says is correct.

Editing a question that is closed *will* automatically put it in the reopen queue but there are a few caveats to this.

1. The question must be edited within 5 days of when it was closed for it to go into the queue. Otherwise, no amount of editing will put it in the queue and you'll have to find another way to get attention to it.
2. Only one such edit will have this effect, so if the question stays closed, it won't go back into the review queue with subsequent edits. - Use your edits wisely. Making minor textual edits that don't address the concerns explained in the comments or close reason is a waste of your review queue edit because it's extremely unlikely that you will have your question reopened.

If you've figured out how to rephrase your question and you now (after more than five days) feel that it's ready to be reopened,  asking about it on meta is *one of the reasons meta exists*, so please don't be discouraged in asking here **if** you've actually made substantial edits to your question and you can explain why you think your question now meets the site's quality standards.

As the [FAQ on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/284336) says:

> If you don't get around to editing the question within five days, or you've edited it but it wasn't reopened, you can make a request on the per-site meta tagging it [support](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support)[reopen-request](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reopen-request). Clearly explain why the question should be reopened (why it's a good, on-topic question, or why it isn't a duplicate). This is also a good way to obtain further clarification about why your question was closed.

You're missing these tags and a strong argument for why this question deserves to be reopened. We need to understand why this question is now a good fit for this site.

If we look at the [revision history](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/posts/2833/revisions), it's not until this recent edit that you've added enough details for this to be more easily addressed on this site. Thank you for that. Adding your location was a major help and I think we're on the road to a question we can answer.